# Saving multiple dataframes within a dictionary into separate dataframes in Python using loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains multiple dataframes that I created using loops. Basically because I want to split the input data file into smaller dataframes with a rule. The main input data file has variables x1, x2, x3, x4, and each smaller data frame has only observations of the main input where x1 = 0, x2 = 0 etc.  like this:

```
data={}
Iteration = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

for n in iteration:
frame = pd.DataFrame(input file)
omit = (frame[n] ==0 )
data[n] = pd.Dataframe(frame.loc[~omit])
```

And data now is a dict that holds all the smaller data frames. But I want to save each of those data frames into Excel. I reckon that to do that, I have to "break" the dict data into small data frames by using loops. So I tried:

```
for n in data.items():
locals()['frame_{n}'.format(n)] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[n])
```

But it doesn't work, because data frames need 2 parameters, but dict has only 1. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dfs` is a dictionary of dataframes, you can write all dataframes to Excel with the dictionary key as the sheet name:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for sheet, df in dfs.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
```

To write as separate files:

```
for key, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_excel(f'___path___/{key}.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way to make the data frames into different excel files, rather than 1 excel file with multiple sheets? I need them separate files..

Comment: @shuu Writing as separate files is easier; see the edit above.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't recognize that "key" needs to change with each iteration and it only creates 1 excel file with the name {key} :( this is what I've faced for awhile too.

Comment: Difficult to discern what's going on without your exact code. I ran the code above on my computer with a test dictionary of dataframes (`dfs`) and it worked fine.

Comment: It might be some typos in my code. Thanks a lot though. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @shuu I think the problem may be that you aren't using an `f'` string -- with an `f` in front of the first `'`. This tells python to format `{key}` with the actual value of `key` in your file name. E.g.--if `key` is `abc` (in that loop iteration), then `f'{key}.xlsx'` will give an Excel file named `abc.xlsx`, whereas `'{key}.xlsx'` will give an Excel file named `{key}.xlsx`.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the case! Thank you for being patient :D such a small typo and I can never tell.